# Appfog / Node.js - What's the best way to store data online?

Tags: mysql, node.js, mongodb, appfog

I have an app online in Node.js on appfog that takes in user data.  I need to store that data as a text file and me able to download it later.  What's the best way to store these files?

I've tried setting up a MySQL or mongodb database, but I am having a lot of trouble.  Is this the correct approach?

Thanks.

Comment: If you are having small chunk of data then you can try storing it on embedded dbs on file system. like derbydb or sqlite

Comment: Appfog doesn't persist the file system.  If your instance gets rebooted anything saved to disk goes bye bye.

Comment: Is there no way to store data online that's not through appfog, such as some sort of database service?  I'm considering having node.js email the data to me.  Is this a possibility?